# Can I pre-render non page components if all the inputs are known in advance

Tags: next.js, app-router, static-site-generation

The homepage of my app renders a sample of data points from a known set, each data point is rendered with the same template and the set itself is finite.

I want to decide which items are part of the subset during runtime by randomly selecting ids at page load and requesting the related item details by calling an api for each selected id.

If I set a dynamic page route to display the single data point details by id I can compute everything in advance with `generateStaticParams`.

If I want to render the subset I selected at runtime in the homepage I will need to render the list as client component, but each single data point is still knowable in advance.

Can I pre-render the set of components that display the data of my finite set of data points the same way that I would pre-render the pages that show the same data for each data point?

**In other words, can I compute in advance a set of component templates (same component with different inputs) then decide at runtime which of them should be rendered in my page?**

Comment: Is you pain point that you don't want to keep making the same api calls for the exact same data every time? And how often is the api data changing - daily, hourly, never?

Comment: a sample of the data points is taken each time the user navigates to the page. I could keep my own cache of the api responses. my question is: I know at build time what this components are going the render, can I pre-render them?

Comment: better said, I know at buildtime all of their possible inputs, can I pre-render all of their outputs and select at runtime which ones to show?